# Hide css <span> @ min-width: 480px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

On my personal site [nineballstudio](http://www.nineballstudio.com) I am encountering a problem with the main headline text `min-width: 480px`. I found out that it was because of the animate.css effect I've used to animate a fade in for this .

Is there a way I can `display:none` for the `span` without it affecting the `span` at other widths? I've also tried the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
    span {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ section 4.1

you can specifiy a particular range of screen widths to apply styles such as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px) { … }
```